# Find directories not containing a certain subdirectory

Tags: linux

I know I can do this to get a list of directories inside /vz/root:

```
find /vz/root/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec echo {} \;
```

But how can I edit this to only list the directories that do not contain a subdirectory called "php-5.3.3"? So if there's 3 directories /vz/root/101, /vz/root/102, and /vz/root/103, and two of them contain php-5.3.3 subdirectory, it would only echo the path of the one that doesn't have it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
find /vz/root/ -maxdepth 1 -type d  \! -exec test -d '{}/php-5.3.3' \; -print | grep -v php-5.3.3 | uniq -w 12 | grep -v '^/vz/root/$'
```

Comment: Thank you! I added maxdepth to your command and it worked perfectly. I was getting loads of errors without the maxdepth. find /vz/root/ -maxdepth 1 -type d  \! -exec test -d '{}/php-5.3.3' \; -print | grep -v php-5.3.3 | uniq -w 12 | grep -v '^/vz/root/$'

Comment: What was the error ?

Comment: Something like proc/101 not found, repeated with all the different numbers from /vz/root

Comment: Fun!  1) This is why the -exec test in find exists, kudos for the excellent use.  2) It wasn't clear to me that the original problem was intended to be used on the root of a filesystem.  You might also use -xdev to prevent the search from searching the proc (or dev, or sys, or tmp, or NFS, or other) filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude the paths that contain php-5.3.3, you can simply use `grep -v`

```
find /root/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo {} \; | grep -v php-5.3.3
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work because php-5.3.3 is a subdirectory. I am searching in /vz/root but php-5.3.3 is inside eg /vz/root/101/php-5.3.3

Comment: I could do it with maxdepth 2, but then I will also need to exclude all the other directory names that I'm not interested in. How would I specify multiple names with grep?

Comment: "How would I specify multiple names with grep?" -- use egrep. For example, egrep -v "(first_name|second_name|third_name)"

Answer (score 1):

You can use **!** as **not** operator.

```
find /vz/root/ -type d -maxdepth 1 ! -ipath '*php-5.3.3*' -exec echo {} \;
```

That would list all the directories under /vz/root/ except the ones that has php-5.3.3 in their path name.

Comment: This doesn't actually work because php-5.3.3 is a subdirectory. I am searching in /vz/root but php-5.3.3 is inside eg /vz/root/101/php-5.3.3. If I run this it's just listing all the directories in /vz/root regardless of whether they contain the php-5.3.3 subdir.

Comment: Damn, you're right. This one is actually a harder piece to solve than I originally thought. Time to spawn a voodoo doll ...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to take something that almost solves it with find and use `find2perl` to create a Perl program that does the same thing.  Then modify the Perl script to do something advanced.  I won't enumerate though because you asked for a variation on the `find` command and this is outside the scope of your request.  Plus, you'd have to know some Perl and I don't want to start a flamewar.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of the accepted answer:

```
find /vz/root/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec test ! -d "{}/php-5.3.3" \; -print
```